# Chart.js adding 200 data at once to the canvas

Tags: javascript

I have an experimental page where is a chart.js canvas.
Right now I add data points one by one from a webwocket data packet.
In that packet I got 200 data, which I want to add to my canvas, but not one by one, but all of it at once.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="lineGraph" class="chart-container">
 <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
</div>
</body>

<script>
  function myFunction1() {
  maxDataPoints = document.getElementById("adatszelesseg").value;
  if(maxDataPoints >= 200){
    animateDur = 0;
    animationisokay = false;
  }else if (maxDataPoints < 200){
    animateDur = 1000;
    animationisokay = true;
  }
  init();
}
  function removeData(){
    dataPlot.data.labels.shift();
    dataPlot.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
  }
  function addData(label, data) {
    if(dataPlot.data.labels.length > maxDataPoints) removeData();
    dataPlot.data.labels.push(label);
    dataPlot.data.datasets[0].data.push(data);
    dataPlot.update();
  }
  function init() {
    dataPlot = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: "rgba(159,170,174,0.2)",
            borderWidth: 1.3,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(232,105,90,0.8)",
            hoverBorderColor: "orange",
          data: [],
          label: "Analog.Sign.(%)",
          borderColor: "#f7f7f7",
          fill: true
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
            fontColor: "white",
            labels: {
                fontColor: "white",
                fontSize: 18
            }
        },
        animation: animationisokay,
        scales: {
        xAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        fontColor: "white",
        fontSize: 18,
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Sec / MicroSec'
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          fontColor: "white",
          fontSize: 18,
          display: true,
        }
      }]
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: animateDur,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
    animation: {
        animationEasing: 'linear',
        duration: animateDur
    }
}
    
    })
};

webSocket1 = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/');

webSocket1.onmessage=function(a){
    var t = a.data;
    if(t.indexOf('}')>-1){
        var j = t.substring(0, t.length - 1);
        var today = new Date();
        var m = today.getSeconds() + ":" + today.getMilliseconds();
        console.log(j);
        addData(m, j);
        }};
</script>
```

So as you can see, I have a websocket event, where my data comes in as a.data.
I put it into a variable called t for further modification.
After that I have to look at it if it is have the string "}" than this is my data.
After that I add the j data to the canvas. And that is repeating while I got my 200 data to the canvas.
The data comes on the websocket almost each microsec.

The problem is I can see on the canvas that there is a delay in the display in each data, like if it is scrolling itself from right to the left.

I tried to collect my 200 data to an array, and pass that array to the canvas but it did not worked.

On the background I have a c++ server code.
I send the data like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datawidth; i++) {
  String json = "";
  json += String(vRealBuff[i] / (float)40.95);
  json += "}";
  webSocket.broadcastTXT(json.c_str(), json.length());
}
```

It is 200 data one by one, but it doesn't matter if I send all of it at once from the server, or collect it on the JavaScript code and add all of it at once.
The data does not display if I add an array of data to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by collecting the data on an array and passing that array to the chart.